# Entity Framework many to many relationship and reach third table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using fluent api to configure many to many relationship between Tags and Courses  in such way :

```
    HasMany(c => c.Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("CourseTags");
                m.MapLeftKey("CourseId");
                m.MapRightKey("TagId");
            });
```

Course has `ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set;}` And Tag has `ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set;}`

However, what if i need to reach CourseTags table inside the code, something like this:

```
EFDbContext _db = new EFDbContext();
_db.CourseTags;
```

Should i create the third table mannualy :

```
Public class CourseTags{
CourseId...;
TagId
}
```

Or what is the best way to configure many to many relationship in entity framework? Would i ever need to reach the third table in code?

Comment: I don't know if you ever want to reach the reference table in your code :) I would only need that, if the table contains more data than the foreign keys. Then you would create a new entity for that relationship table like you said. But in your case everything looks fine for me and this is the normal approach with entity framework.

Comment: Thank, now i feel more confident